# PowerShell list inherited methods with Get-Member

Tags: powershell

I am exploring what pipeline functionality is also available as methods. For example...
`@('1', '2', '3', '2') | where {$_ -in @('2')}` will return the two '2'. But I can also do...
`@('1', '2', '3', '2').Where({$_ -in @('2')})` and get the same result.

I also want to `Group`, and while
`@('1', '2', '3', '2') | group {$_.Count -gt 1}` doesn't do the actual grouping I want, it does... something. But
`@('1', '2', '3', '2').Group({$_.Count -gt 1})` fails with `Method invocation failed because [System.String] does not contain a method named 'Group'.`

So that got me looking for what IS available as intrinsic methods.
`@('1') | Get-Member -MemberType Method -Force | Format-Table` doesn't even include `Where` and yet the Method is there. So I assume it is inheriting that method. But I don't know how to include inherited Methods. I though `-Force` would do it but it doesn't, nor does `-View` provide any more detail.

Is there a way to explore these intrinsic methods such as `.Where()`? And perhaps tangentially, is there a way to Group as a method rather than with the pipeline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Dabombber's answer is helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65455045/45375), but let me try to give a **systematic overview**:

The `.Where()` and `.ForEach()` [array methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Arrays#methods-of-arrays) are instances of what are known as [***intrinsic members***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Intrinsic_Members); no other such intrinsic array-processing (collection-processing) methods exist as of PowerShell 7.1

***Intrinsic members* are members (properties and methods) that the *PowerShell engine* exposes on objects of *any* type** - *except* if the object has a *native .NET type member* of the same name, which takes precedence.

**Discovery limitations**, as of PowerShell 7.1 / late 2020:

- Intrinsic members cannot be discovered via [`Get-Member`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-member)

  - [GitHub proposal #11798](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/11798) aims to introduce this ability.
- Tab completion works only for `.Where()` and `.ForEach()` (on collection values), but not for other intrinsic members, such as the `.psobject` property (see below).
- However, they are *documented* in the  conceptual [about_Intrinsic_Members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Intrinsic_Members) help topic.

In short: as of this writing, **you cannot discover intrinsic members *programmatically***.

---

**List of intrinsic members**:

- **Intrinsic members that enable *unified treatment of collections (arrays) and scalars***:

  - PowerShell adds **`.Count` and `.Length` properties** (aliases of each other) even to *scalars* (assuming they don't have type-native properties of the same name), with an non-null scalar sensibly reporting `1` (e.g., `(42).Count`), and `$null` reporting `0` (`$null.Count`)

    - **Pitfalls**:

      - **Accessing these properties while `Set-StrictMode -Version 2` or higher is in effect unexpectedly causes statement-terminating errors**, because the engine treats them as non-existent; this long-standing bug is discussed in [GitHub issue #2798](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2798).
      - [`IEnumerable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.IEnumerable) instances such as returned by LINQ methods aren't collections per se, and calling `.Count` on them *triggers enumeration* and returns a `.Count` property value from each enumerated element instead (which defaults to `1`); e.g., `[Linq.Enumerable]::Range(1,3).Count` returns array `1, 1, 1` instead of `3`.
      - There is a ***bug* in *Windows PowerShell*** (as of the latest *and final* version, 5.1), which has since been corrected in [*PowerShell (Core)*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md): **`[pscustomobject]` instances unexpectedly do *not* have `.Count` and `.Length` properties** (see [GitHub issue #3671](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3671) for the original bug report) - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68355717/45375).
  - Similarly, PowerShell allows you to ***index* even into a *scalar*** (again, unless preempted by a type-native indexer, such as that of [`XmlElement`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Xml.XmlElement)); e.g., `(42)[0]` and `(42)[-1]` both return `42`, i.e. the scalar itself.
- ***Collection-processing* intrinsic members:**

  - These are (only) the **`.Where()` and `.ForEach()` methods** discussed above.
  - Note that, in the the interest of unified treatment of collections and scalars, these methods also work on *scalars*; e.g., `(42).ForEach({ $_ + 1 })` yields `43`.
  - **Pitfalls**:

    - In *Windows PowerShell* (since fixed in *PowerShell [Core] 7+*), *some* types of scalars - notably `[pscustomobject]` and `[xml]` - do *not* provide these methods, which should be considered a *bug*.
    - The [`System.Collections.Generic.List<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.Generic.List-1) collection type has its own `.ForEach()` method that therefore shadows PowerShell's; this type-native method neither supports the use of `$_` nor producing output.
- **Intrinsic members for *reflection* (not available on `$null`):**

  - The **`.psobject` property** is a rich source of reflection on any object, such as its list of properties; e.g., `(Get-Date).psobject.Properties` lists metadata about all public properties of instances of [`System.DateTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.DateTime).
  - `.pstypenames` (also available as `.psobject.TypeNames`) lists all [ETS (Extended Type System)](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/6763) type names associated with an instance; by default, the property contains the full names of the object's .NET type and its base type(s).
  - The `.psbase`, `.psextended`, and `.psadapted` properties return categorized *subsets* of type members, namely .NET-native, ETS-added, and *adapted* members.

    - *Adapted* members are members that surface information from a different data representation as if they were native type members, notably in the context of CIM (WMI) and [PowerShell's adaptation of the XML DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49213568/45375).
    - For instance, `[xml]` ([`System.Xml.XmlDocument`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Xml.XmlDocument)) instances have members in all three categories; try `$xml = ([xml] '<someElement>some text</someElement>'); '-- .psbase:'; $xml.psbase; '-- .psextended'; $xml.psextended; '-- .psadapted'; $xml.psadapted`

Answer (score 1):

Your arrays are getting unrolled through the pipeline, so `@('1') | Get-Member -MemberType Method -Force` is showing  members for a string.

You can bypass that by sending it as the second object of an array

```
,@('1') | Get-Member -MemberType Method
```

outputting it without enumeration

```
Write-Output -NoEnumerate @('1') | Get-Member -MemberType Method
```

or passing it as a parameter instead of through the pipeline.

```
Get-Member -InputObject @('1') -MemberType Method
```

---

Some of the methods may also be static, so you could use the `-Static` switch for `Get-Member`.

There is a list of array methods [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arrays#methods-of-arrays), although I have no idea why not all of them show up, perhaps it's an intentional part of the `Get-Member` cmdlet or maybe they're part of the PowerShell language itself rather than proper methods.

Comment: Ugh, gotta remember that goofy single element array unroll behavior! Though in this case that still doesn't expose the `.Where()` method. Though that link does answer the question "Is there a Group method?" Nope. :(

Comment: Yea, I'm aware I don't really answer your main question (luckily mklement0 does), but it's a little too much for a comment. As for grouping, if it's purely for display purposes, you may want to play with the `GroupBy` element of [formatting files](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/scripting/developer/format/list-view-groupby).