# Fetching JSON with PowerShell - How do I fetch all keys under multiple arrays?

Tags: json, powershell, powershell-5.1, convertfrom-json

I'm trying to build a json file that'll be used in our diverse scripts to fetch our server details.
The same script will be used across all our environments that contains multiple products and components. Here's the kind of json file I'm working with:

```
{
    "DEV" : {
        "Product1" : [
            {"serverName" : "hostname1", "isWebServer" : "true"},
            {"serverName" : "hostname2", "isWebServer" : "false"}
        ],
        "Product2" : [
            {"serverName" : "hostname3", "isWebServer" : "false"},
            {"serverName" : "hostname4", "isWebServer" : "true"}
        ]
    }
}
```

JSON file is imported into a variable and I'm able to use it successfully.

`$jsonFile = Get-Content -Path "C:\temp\test.json" -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json`

What I'm trying to do in my PowerShell script is fetch all serverName that is configured with key `"isWebServer" : "true"`

I can successfully achieve my goal if I'm drilling down on each arrays directly.

`($jsonFile.DEV.Product1 | Where-Object {$_.isWebServer -eq "true"}).serverName`

However, I'm unable to achieve the same success when I want to fetch all web servers from the whole DEV environment. I'm looking for something like this but that will actually return something.

`($jsonFile.DEV | Where-Object {$_.isWebServer -eq "true"}).serverName`

How can I fetch everything under all arrays within an object ? I'm used to XPATHs in which I can use wildcards for that kind of scenario but I haven't found the equivalent in JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possible solution:

```
$json.DEV.PSObject.Properties.Value.Where{ $_.isWebServer -eq 'true' }.serverName
```

The hidden (*[intrinsic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65459795/7571258)*) `PSObject` member allows us to access properties (`Product1`, `Product2`, ...) of the `DEV` object, without having to know their names in advance.

Then, using [member access enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_member-access_enumeration), we get an array of all `Value` members of the [`PSPropertyInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.pspropertyinfo?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0#properties) objects stored in `PSObject.Properties`.

To filter the server objects, the intrinsic method [`Where`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arrays?view=powershell-7.2#where) is used to return only the servers matching the given condition. Feel free to use `Where-Object` instead:

```
$json.DEV.PSObject.Properties.Value | 
    Where-Object isWebServer -eq 'true' | 
    ForEach-Object serverName
```

Though I prefer the intrinsic methods as they are faster than the pipeline (less overhead) and more succinct to write.

Answer (score -1):

It looks similar to what I did a long time ago. See if [this](https://github.com/mailforsachin/PowershellScripts/blob/master/XMLToJSONConvertor) helps.